# jquery UL LI collapse all of the expanded child under it

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a list order looking  like these:

```
<ul>
    <li>level 1 a
        <ul>
            <li>level 2 a
                <ul>
                    <li>level 3 a</li>
                    <li>level 3 b</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>level 2 b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>level 1 b
        <ul>
            <li>level 2 c
                <ul>
                    <li>level 3 c</li>
                    <li>level 3 c</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>level 2 d</li>
            <li>level 2 e</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and jquery looking like these:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').click(function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
      $(this).children('ul').show();
      $(this).prev().children('ul').hide();
      $(this).siblings().children('ul li ul').hide();
      $(this).next().children('ul').hide();
  }); 
  $('li > ul').hide();
});
```

**current situation:**

1) i click on **level 1 a** then **level 2 a**, now level 1 a and level 2 a are expanded

2) i click on **level 1 b**, then i click back the **level 1 a**, i still see the level 1 a and its child is expanded.

**the outcome i want is:**

when i click back level 1 a, it will collapse everything, instead of showing everything that i clicked before, same goes to level 1 b, if i click that 1st.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hr5bxof/)

any help would be great. thanks

Comment: So to be clear, when you *re-open* level 1 a, it should only show the first level of the tree.  It should not remember that previously you dove down 2 levels, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call hide on `children ul` whenever a `sibling` `li` is clicked using this

```
 $('li').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).siblings('li').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings('li').children('ul').hide()
    })
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).siblings('li').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings('li').children('ul').hide()
    })
    
      $(this).children('ul').children('li').children('ul').hide()
   
   
    ev.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent('ul').show();
     $(this).children('li').hide();
    $(this).siblings('li').children('ul li ul').hide();
    $(this).children('ul').show();
    $(this).prev('li').children('ul li ul').hide();
    $(this).next().children('ul').hide();
  });
  $('li > ul').hide();
});
```

```css
current situation: 1) i click on level 1 a then level 2 a,
now level 1 a and level 2 a are expanded 2) i click on level 1 b,
then i click back the level 1 a,
i still see the level 1 a and its child is expanded. the outcome i want is: when i click back level 1 a,
it will collapse everything,
instead of showing everything that i clicked before,
same goes to level 1 b,
if i click that 1st.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>level 1 a
    <ul>
      <li>level 2 a
        <ul>
          <li>level 3 a</li>
          <li>level 3 b</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>level 2 b</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>level 1 b
    <ul>
      <li>level 2 c
        <ul>
          <li>level 3 c</li>
          <li>level 3 c</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>level 2 d</li>
      <li>level 2 e</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: when i click back the level 1 a, i still see the child of level 2 a, it should be hidden